# Setting a countdown timer with time picker dialog android

Tags: android, android-studio, timepicker

My end goal is to have a countdown timer that is set using the time picker dialog in android. As of now I have a time picker that can be set to any time, and I have a countdown timer. So my question is how do I set the textview in my countdown timer to what was set in my time picker. In my code I just have my countdown timer set to three minutes, but I would like it set to the time picker dialogs set time.

Here is what I have...

```
public class SleepTimer extends AppCompatActivity {
TimePicker myTimePicker;
Button buttonstartSetDialog;
TextView textAlarmPrompt;
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
final static int RQS_1 = 1;
Button btnStart, btnStop;
TextView textViewTime;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sleep_timer);

    btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStop= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    textViewTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);



    final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(180000, 1000);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.start();
        }
    });
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });

    textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);
    buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
    buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
            openTimePickerDialog(false);
        }
    });


}

private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
            SleepTimer.this,
            onTimeSetListener,
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            is24r);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Sleep Time");

    timePickerDialog.show();
}

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){

            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        setAlarm(calSet);

    }};


public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    /**
     * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
     *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
     *                          is called.
     * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
     *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
     */

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
}
```

If anyone knows how to do this please respond. Thanks:)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly, you are trying to set a textView to whatever was chosen in the timePicker dialog?

Comment: Yes is there something wrong with that

Comment: No just making sure before I post a solution.

Comment: I updated my answer let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First change this method so it looks like this

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        timer = new CounterClass((minute * 60 * 1000) + (hourOfDay * 60* 60 * 1000), 1000);
        long millis = (minute * 60 * 1000) + (hourOfDay * 60* 60 * 1000);
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);

    }};
```

Then remove `final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(180000, 1000)`
and add it as a field instead as

```
CounterClass timer;
```

This code sets the TextView and also updates your counter with the time picked. But I reused your code and now we have the same code repeating which is not good. Extract it into a method so we don't repeat ourselves.

COPY PASTE EDITION

```
public class SleepTimer extends AppCompatActivity {
TimePicker myTimePicker;
Button buttonstartSetDialog;
TextView textAlarmPrompt;
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
final static int RQS_1 = 1;
Button btnStart, btnStop;
TextView textViewTime;
CounterClass timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sleep_timer);

    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);




    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.start();
        }
    });
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });

    textAlarmPrompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);
    buttonstartSetDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
    buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
            openTimePickerDialog(false);
        }
    });


}

private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
            SleepTimer.this,
            onTimeSetListener,
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            is24r);
    timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Sleep Time");

    timePickerDialog.show();
}

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    timer = new CounterClass((minute * 60 * 1000) + (hourOfDay * 60* 60 * 1000), 1000);
    long millis = (minute * 60 * 1000) + (hourOfDay * 60* 60 * 1000);
    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
    System.out.println(hms);
    textViewTime.setText(hms);

}};


public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    /**
     * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
     *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
     *                          is called.
     * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
     *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
     */

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
}
```

Comment: It says that getCurrentHour, and getCurrentMinute are not static methods and cannot be referenced in static context. What does this mean. Sorry I am really new to java.

Comment: Make sure `timePicker` is lowercase or at least refers to the variable, not to the class.

Comment: @SebastianRoth actually the whole solution I gave him was wrong I was using a timePicker element instead of a dialog. I updated my answer.

Comment: @noev where is `CounterClass` coming from?

Comment: It's a nested class which he provided.

Comment: But this does not do anything to the text view.

Comment: I added textViewTime.setText(hms); also after you press start the countdown works.

Comment: @Leyton I updated my answer a few times, so maybe you don't have the newest changes :)

Comment: Im not sure where you want me to put this could you please elaborate

Comment: @Leyton I edited my answer with a copy paste edition. Now you can just copy paste that whole thing and everything works. Please let me know when everything works. It's 3:43AM where I'm from and this is the final thing i want to do before I go to sleep .

Comment: @noev hello, how can i keep the selection-result of  textViewTime.setText(hms); in every activity?

Comment: @MathiasStavrou I'm not sure I understand your problem. If you just need a place to store the data you could use a singleton(google android singleton).

Comment: @noev First of all thank you . i use sleep timer inside Fragment , i have three pages . when i select through timepicker the time and send in textView working perfect. But i want in every fragment to show timer not only in that specific page. I use SharedPreferences to store data and  inside if is visible fragment retrieve data , but i lose synchronization
     public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
            if (this.isVisible()) { }} how can i toke the CountDownTimer who is working and send it in every fragment-page?

Comment: @MathiasStavrou This is really unrelated, create another SO question, post code and I can help you there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470873/countdown-timer-in-textview-when-viewpager-change